# Would a computer-build tag be off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-questions

In the last week (my first week here :p) I've see that there is a lot of questions about their computer build.

Would a computer build tag be off topic, or should it start been considered as on topic with that tag?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Closing the question.

Edit: Damn. Cant close questions right now.

Comment: There's no need to close the question. Don't worry about it. ;)

Comment: So where should we ask a question about computer build? Which Stackexchange website would hold that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computer Build questions are off-topic on our site, and therefore a tag would be too. We don't create tags for questions considered to be off-topic, and although a [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag does exist, that is because it was created *before* game recommendation questions were considered off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Usually questions like that get closed, primarily because they ask for buying recommendations, which are a) subjective, and b) too time sensitive.